# How do I sort all database data using Tablesorter?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, tablesorter

I'm using the jQuery Plugin called [Tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter).

So far my table can sort for the rows that are shown on each individual page. However, I would like to implement it so that when I sort the table based on a column heading the table sorts all the data in the database and updates the table to show the sorted data.

How would I implement this?

My jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('#keywords').tablesorter(); 
});
```

My View:

```
<div class="col-md-11">
  <table id="keywords" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Added on</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @events.each do |event| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= event.title %></td>
        <td><%= event.location %></td>
        <td><%= event.created_at %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_event_path(event), class: "btn btn-default" %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy',event,method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-default" %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <%= will_paginate @events %>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Controller action:

```
def new
  @event  = Event.new 
  @events = Event.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20).order('id DESC')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ruby, but I think you'll need to use the tablesorter pager widget or plugin, for which you will need to apply some of the ajax widget options. The tablesorter documentation has an example of the pager widget [here](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-pager-ajax.html), and the [main documentation page](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) has more info and links to other relevant examples.